# Cleaning the harddrive

Tags: 12.04, server, headless

I am using a headless Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab111.12 i686).

I recently got a message that the harddisk was full. Is there a way to download all file paths with sizes and to visualize it under windows 7 so I can figure out what to remove?

Or is there a bash command for cleaning the harddrive of this headless server intelligently?

Comment: you may first check the directory containing your logs (usually /var/log) to see if some logfile has grown over the time (no logrotate? verbose (debug) logging used by some service?). Then you may check your drive running find searching for files above a given size (eg. find / -size +1G). ohh... and have an eye to your /tmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
du -s -c -h /var
du -s -c -h /tmp
```

and do it for each and every directory that you suspect might have grown
and do a clean up accordingly.